# HTML Print Pages to PDF fixed header and footer cutting off overflow div

Tags: javascript, html, css, pdf

I am trying to figure out how to add a header and a footer on each page printed out using a web browser. I have a simple html page that has a header and a footer. I also have a body that requires overflow. I cannot figure out how to get the header and the footer to not be cut off on each page printed out.

This is my desired output for every page.. notice the header and the footer with the content in the middle not being cut off
[image: This is my desired output for every page]

this is what i'm getting after the first output page (this is actually the second page of the document when printing to pdf).. Notice body content is being overflowed to the next page and the header is being covered.
[image]

**I am wondering if this is even possible to break up a body based on the printed page made by the web browser.**

Here is the Code:

```css
div.body {
    font-size: 18px;
}
@media print {
    /* print styles go here */
    div.body {
      margin-top: 20px;
      margin-bottom: 100px;
      page-break-inside: avoid;
      padding-top: 1cm;
      padding-bottom: 1cm;
    }
    @page {
      size: auto;   /* auto is the initial value */

      /* this affects the margin in the printer settings */
      margin: 25mm 25mm 25mm 25mm;
    }
    div.divFooter {
      bottom: 0;
      background-color: #ffffff;
      height: 50px;
      margin-top: -20px;
      left: 0;
      font-size: small;
      width:100%;
      text-align: center;
      position:fixed;
      left:0
    }
    div.divHeader {
      position: fixed;
      height:100px;
      top:0;
      margin-bottom: -20px;
      width:100%;
      position:fixed;
      left:0
    }

}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
</head>

<div class="divHeader"><p>This is my Header</p></div>

  <div class="body">
    Hello this is a test!
    <br>Hello this is a test!
    <br>Hello this is a test!
    <br>Hello this is a test!
    <br>Hello this is a test!
    <br>Hello this is a test!
    <br>Hello this is a test!
    <br>Hello this is a test!
    <br>Hello this is a test!
    <br>Hello this is a test!
    <br>Hello this is a test!
    <br>Hello this is a test!
    <br>Hello this is a test!
    <br>Hello this is a test!
    <br>Hello this is a test!
    <br>Hello this is a test!
    <br>Hello this is a test!
    <br>Hello this is a test!
    <br>Hello this is a test!
    <br>Hello this is a test!
    <br>Hello this is a test!
    <br>Hello this is a test!
    <br>Hello this is a test!
    <br>Hello this is a test!
    <br>Hello this is a test!
    <br>Hello this is a test!
    <br>Hello this is a test!
    <br>Hello this is a test!
    <br>Hello this is a test!
    <br>Hello this is a test!
    <br>Hello this is a test!
    <br>Hello this is a test!
    <br>Hello this is a test!
    <br>Hello this is a test!
    <br>Hello this is a test!
    <br>Hello this is a test!
    <br>Hello this is a test!
    <br>Hello this is a test!
    <br>Hello this is a test!
    <br>Hello this is a test!
    <br>Hello this is a test!
    <br>Hello this is a test!
    <br>Hello this is a test!
    <br>Hello this is a test!
    <br>Hello this is a test!
    <br>Hello this is a test!
    <br>Hello this is a test!
    <br>Hello this is a test!
    <br>Hello this is a test!
    <br>Hello this is a test!
    <br>Hello this is a test!
    <br>Hello this is a test!
    <br>Hello this is a test!
    <br>Hello this is a test!
    <br>Hello this is a test!
    <br>Hello this is a test!
    <br>Hello this is a test!
    <br>Hello this is a test!
    <br>Hello this is a test!
    <br>Hello this is a test!
    <br>Hello this is a test!
    <br>Hello this is a test!
    <br>Hello this is a test!
    <br>Hello this is a test!
    <br>Hello this is a test!
    <br>Hello this is a test!
    <br>Hello this is a test!
    <br>Hello this is a test!
    <br>Hello this is a test!
    <br>Hello this is a test!
    <br>Hello this is a test!
    <br>Hello this is a test!
    <br>Hello this is a test!
    <br>Hello this is a test!
    <br>Hello this is a test!
    <br>Hello this is a test!
    <br>Hello this is a test!
    <br>Hello this is a test!
    <br>Hello this is a test!
    <br>Hello this is a test!
    <br>Hello this is a test!
    <br>Hello this is a test!
    <br>Hello this is a test!
    <br>Hello this is a test!
    <br>Hello this is a test!
    <br>Hello this is a test!
    <br>Hello this is a test!
    <br>Hello this is a test!
    <br>Hello this is a test!
    <br>Hello this is a test!
    <br>Hello this is a test!
    <br>Hello this is a test!
    <br>Hello this is a test!
    <br>Hello this is a test!
    <br>Hello this is a test!
    <br>Hello this is a test!
    <br>Hello this is a test!
    <br>Hello this is a test!
    <br>Hello this is a test!
    <br>Hello this is a test!
    <br>Hello this is a test!
    <br>Hello this is a test!
    <br>Hello this is a test!
    <br>Hello this is a test!
    <br>Hello this is a test!
    <br>Hello this is a test!
    <br>Hello this is a test!
    <br>Hello this is a test!
    <br>Hello this is a test!
  </div>


<div class="divFooter"><p>This is my footer</p></div>

</html>
```

Comment: Were you able to fix your problem? I having a similar problem, the header overflow...